# Find the distribution of the maximum of a Wiener Process with negative drift

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

So.. what I have now is

Let $M=max\{W_t; 0\leq t <\infty\}$ since $W_0=0$, $M\geq 0$ with probability 1. So,

$P(M>x)=P(T_x<\infty)$ where $T_x$ is the stopping time, so we now use the martingale $e^{2\mu W_t/\sigma^2}$ and since it is a martingale and uniformly bounded, we have
$E[e^{2\mu W_{T_x}/\sigma^2}]=1$, so...

$E[e^{2\mu W_{T_x}/\sigma^2}]=e^{2\mu x / \sigma^2}P(T_x<\infty)+0 P(T_x=\infty) \Rightarrow P(M>x)=e^{2x\mu/\sigma^2}$

But I'm not sure if everything I did makes sense..

Comment: Am I right in guessing that $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are the drift rate and variance?  That is, $W_t = \sigma B_t - \mu t$ where $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion?

Comment: Talking about $W_{T_x}$ when there is a positive probability that $T_x = \infty$ is very questionable.  Usually, it is better to apply optional stopping to $W_{t \wedge T_x}$ and let $t \to \infty$.

Comment: Yes, Nate. that is correct.

Comment: Hm I see what you mean. Then I could use something like 0 \leq e^{2\mu W_{t\wedge T_x}/\sigma^2}\leq e^{-2\mu x/\sigma^2} but then that gives the same answer still right?

Comment: You need an extra step to argue that on the event $\{T_x = \infty\}$ we have $W_t \to -\infty$ almost surely, so that in fact $e^{2 \mu W_{t \wedge T_x}/\sigma^2} \to e^{2 \mu x / \sigma^2} 1_{\{T_x < \infty\}}$ almost surely.  Then you can use dominated convergence.

Comment: Is my claim about $E[e^{2\mu W_{t_x}/\sigma^2}]=1$ correct though?

Comment: Is it true? As it turns out, yes. Is it adequately justified? Not by what you have written. Without the extra step I mentioned, it's not even well defined.

Comment: How do you show that the expectation is 1? Any hints? I'm not too sure where to begin with it.

Answer (score 5):

Let

$$W_t := \sigma B_t - \mu \cdot t$$

be a Brownian motion with drift $\mu>0$ and

$$T_x := \inf\{t \geq 0; W_t \geq x\}.$$

Using the stationarity and independence of the increments of the Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$, it is not difficult to see that $\left(\exp\left[\frac{2\mu W_t}{\sigma^2}\right]\right)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale. In particular, we find by the optional stopping theorem

$$\mathbb{E} \bigg( \exp \bigg[ \frac{2\mu W_{t \wedge T_x}}{\sigma^2} \bigg] \bigg) = 1$$

for any $t \geq 0$. Obviously,

$$\begin{align*}\mathbb{E} \bigg( \exp \bigg[ \frac{2\mu W_{t \wedge T_x}}{\sigma^2} \bigg] \bigg) &= \mathbb{E} \bigg( \exp \bigg[ \frac{2\mu W_{t}}{\sigma^2} \bigg] \cdot 1_{\{T_x=\infty\}} \bigg) + \mathbb{E} \bigg( \exp \bigg[ \frac{2\mu W_{t \wedge T_x}}{\sigma^2} \bigg] \cdot 1_{\{T_x<\infty\}} \bigg) \\ &=:I_1+I_2. \end{align*}$$

For $I_2$ we see that the integrand is bounded by $\exp\left(\frac{2\mu x}{\sigma^2}\right)$ and that $T_x \wedge t \to T_x$ as $t \to \infty$. Therefore, the dominated convergence theorem yields

$$I_2 \stackrel{t \to \infty}{\to} \mathbb{E} \bigg( \exp \bigg[ \frac{2\mu W_{T_x}}{\sigma^2} \bigg] \cdot 1_{\{T_x<\infty\}} \bigg) = \exp \left(\frac{2\mu x}{\sigma^2} \right) \cdot \mathbb{P}(T_x<\infty).$$

It remains to prove that $I_1 \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$. First of all, we recall that

$$\frac{B_t}{t} \to 0 \qquad \text{as} \, t \to \infty.$$

This means that

$$W_t = t \cdot \left( \sigma \frac{B_t}{t}- \mu \right) \to - \infty, \qquad t \to \infty.$$

Invoking again the dominated convergence theorem, we see that $I_1 \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$. Hence

$$1 = \lim_{t \to \infty} (I_1+I_2) = \exp \left(\frac{2\mu x}{\sigma^2} \right) \cdot \mathbb{P}(T_x<\infty),$$

i.e.

$$\mathbb{P}(T_x<\infty) = \exp \left(-\frac{2\mu x}{\sigma^2} \right).$$